# The best way to make a simple and accurate stopwatch

Tags: vb.net, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I have a project that I have to do a Stopwatch. It works but it's not accurate compared to the Windows Timer. Also, I want to know if there is another efficient and simple way to do it, if so, how can I do it?. The interval of the Timer is 1.

Here's my code:

```
    Dim min As Integer = 30
    Dim seg As Integer = 59
    Dim mseg As Integer = 99
    Private Sub tmTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmTimer.Tick

        If lblStopWatch.Text = "00:00:00" Then
            lblStopWatch.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
            tmTimer.Enabled = False
            min = 30
            seg = 59
            mseg = 99
        Else
            mseg -= 1
            If mseg < 0 Then
                mseg = 99
                seg -= 1
                If seg < 0 Then
                    seg = 59
                    min -= 1
                End If
            End If

            If min < 10 And seg < 10 And mseg < 10 Then
                lblStopWatch.Text = "0" + min.ToString + ":0" + seg.ToString + ":0" + mseg.ToString
            ElseIf min < 10 And seg < 10 Then
                lblStopWatch.Text = "0" + min.ToString + ":0" + seg.ToString + ":" + mseg.ToString
            ElseIf min < 10 And mseg < 10 Then
                lblStopWatch.Text = "0" + min.ToString + ":" + seg.ToString + ":0" + mseg.ToString
            ElseIf seg < 10 And mseg < 10 Then
                lblStopWatch.Text = min.ToString + ":0" + seg.ToString + ":0" + mseg.ToString
            Else
                If mseg < 10 Then
                    lblStopWatch.Text = min.ToString + ":" + seg.ToString + ":0" + mseg.ToString
                ElseIf seg < 10 Then
                    lblStopWatch.Text = min.ToString + ":0" + seg.ToString + ":" + mseg.ToString
                ElseIf min < 10 Then
                    lblStopWatch.Text = "0" + min.ToString + ":" + seg.ToString + ":" + mseg.ToString
                Else
                    lblStopWatch.Text = min.ToString + ":" + seg.ToString + ":" + mseg.ToString
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

And here's the Button that can start the Timer:

```
Private Sub btnAcept_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAcept.Click

     lblCronometro.ForeColor = Color.RoyalBlue
        lblCronometro.Text = "30:00:00"
        tmCronometro.Enabled = True
        tmCronometro.Start()

End Sub
```

If the example is in C# or vb, I can get both.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by, *"it's not accurate compared to the Windows Timer"*. You're using a "Windows Timer", aren't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINTS**

If you want to do it yourself instead of using the existing `StopWatch` class, another option would be to keep track of the time that the stopwatch started (`start`) and how long the stopwatch has been running (`elapsed`).

With the `start` value, we can calculate the `elapsed` time in the timer's `Tick` event like:

```cs
// elapsed is a TimeSpan object
elapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
```

If we add the ability to stop the stopwatch and then start it again (without resetting it), then we have to take that "downtime" into consideration. We can do this in our `Start` button click event by subtracting the `elapsed` time from the current time and using *that* value as the start time:

```cs
// start is a DateTime object
start = DateTime.Now.Subtract(elapsed);
```

Then, when we want to display the elapsed time to the user, we can just use our `elapsed` field and format it like: `hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds` using a custom format string.

```cs
// I noticed you're doing a countdown timer, so we want to display the difference
// between the original duration of 30 minutes and the elapsed time we've been running
lblStopwatch.Text = (duration - elapsed).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.ff");
```

---

**ANSWER**

If those hints aren't enough, here's a sample project using that strategy:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DateTime _startTime;
    private TimeSpan _elapsedTime;

    // The starting duration for the countdown timer
    private readonly TimeSpan _duration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResetTimer();
    }

    private void ResetTimer()
    {
        _startTime = DateTime.Now;
        _elapsedTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
        UpdateStopwatchDisplay();
    }

    private void UpdateStopwatchDisplay()
    {
        // Display the current duration to the user
        lblStopwatch.ForeColor = timer1.Enabled ? Color.RoyalBlue : Color.DarkGray;
        lblStopwatch.Text = (_duration - _elapsedTime).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.ff");
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Subtract 'elapsed' from 'now' to account for any stoppage time
        _startTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_elapsedTime);
        UpdateStopwatchDisplay();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        UpdateStopwatchDisplay();
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetTimer();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Update elapsed time
        _elapsedTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_startTime);

        // Stop the timer if we've reached our duration
        if (_elapsedTime >= _duration)
        {
            _elapsedTime = _duration;
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        UpdateStopwatchDisplay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework includes a `Stopwatch` class so you should use that. It is perfectly accurate, at least to the degree that your code executes its methods on time. It has methods to `Start`, `Stop`, `Restart` and `Reset` and it provides the elapsed time as a `TimeSpan` that you can format directly instead of all that concatenation. The only thing you would use the `Timer` for is to allow you to display the current elapsed time in the `Label`. E.g.

```vb
Private ReadOnly stopwatch As New Stopwatch

Private Sub startButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles startButton.Click
    DisplayElapsedTime()

    stopwatch.Start()
    displayTimer.Start()

    startButton.Enabled = False
    stopButton.Enabled = True
    restartButton.Enabled = True
    resetButton.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub stopButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles stopButton.Click
    stopwatch.Stop()
    displayTimer.Stop()

    DisplayElapsedTime()

    startButton.Enabled = True
    stopButton.Enabled = False
    restartButton.Enabled = False
    resetButton.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub restartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles restartButton.Click
    stopwatch.Restart()

    DisplayElapsedTime()
End Sub

Private Sub resetButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles resetButton.Click
    stopwatch.Reset()

    DisplayElapsedTime()
End Sub

Private Sub displayTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles displayTimer.Tick
    DisplayElapsedTime()
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayElapsedTime()
    elapsedTimeLabel.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("m\:ss\.fff")
End Sub
```